# ¿Cómo obtengo el valor de una textarea html con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo esta etiqueta textarea y necesito obtener el valor con JQuery, para posteriormente usarla en Javascript.

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="contenido-post" placeholder="Escribe algo"></textarea>
```

Con valor, me refiero a lo que el usuario va a ingresar.

Comment: La opción anteriormente mostrada por @Vick Muñoz es valida, pero mi recomendación es que experimentes con JQuery y pruebes otras alternativas ya que el uso de id's a la larga puede ser una mala idea ya que los id's han de ser únicos. (prueba a trabajar con otro selector como las clases). Por donde empezar. Adjunto la web oficial del framework(en inglés), que es de fácil lectura y comprensión: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/ Espero haberte ayudado, Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el texto de la etiqueta `<textarea></textarea>` lo seleccionas por su **id** y obtienes el texto con `val()`, cualquier duda hazla saber. :D

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#obtener').click(function(){
  
  var contenido = $('#contenido-post').val();

console.log(contenido);
  
  })


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" id="contenido-post" placeholder="Escribe algo"></textarea>

<button type="button" id="obtener">Obtener Texto</button>
```